# Treat a void function as a value

Tags: c, function

I'm writing some terrible, terrible code, and I need a way to put a free() in the middle of a statement. The actual code is:

```
int main(){
    return printf("%s", isPalindrome(fgets(malloc(1000), 1000, stdin))?"Yes!\n":"No!\n") >= 0;
    // leak 1000 bytes of memory
}
```

I was using alloca(), but I can't be sure that will actually work on my target computer. My problem is that free returns void, so my code has this error message:

```
error: void value not ignored as it ought to be
```

The obvious idea I had was:

```
int myfree(char *p){
    free(p);
    return 0;
}
```

Which is nice in that it makes the code even more unreadable, but I'd prefer not to add another function.

I also briefly tried treating `free()` as a function pointer, but I don't know if that would work, and I don't know enough about C to do it properly.

Note: I know this is a terrible idea. Don't try this at home kids.

EDIT: Thanks a lot guys, I got it working by changing my one-line `isPalindrome()` function to this:

```
return (...)?(calls == 1?free(pLeft),1:1):(calls == 1?free(pLeft),0:0);
```

(calls is keeping track of recursion depth)

No more memory leaks!

Comment: I'm sorry. What is your problem!?

Comment: What exactly is the problem with adding another function call? If that's the most obvious way to go around the issue, and it works, why not?

Comment: You are right, it is a terrible idea, so why do it? Why not just use an array of char on the stack?

Comment: I guess it depends whether one considers it legitimate to impose silly constraints on one's own code. "Play", as I believe it's called by psychologists ;-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't know quite where you're going to shoehorn this in but if you need an expression that frees a pointer `p` as a side effect and evalutes to 0 then you can just use this.

```
(free(p), 0)
```

Answer (score 3):

A comma operator, maybe?

```
char *buf;
printf("%s", isPalindrome(fgets(buf = malloc(1000), 1000, stdin))? (free(buf), "Yes!\n"):(free(buf), "No!\n") >= 0;
```

Not sure whether you're "allowed" to use a variable, though.

Or define a wrapper for isPalindrome which frees its parameter:

```
printf("%s", isPalindrome_free(fgets(buf = malloc(1000), 1000, stdin))? "Yes!\n":"No!\n")) >= 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

### Turn it inside out

1. Do the **printf** inside ur    **isPalindrome** function.
2. Inside **isPalindrome** Call **free()** after the printf and return from the function.
3. **Main()** remains the one-liner it is **isPalindrome()**

Comment: Thanks a lot, I couldn't have made it one line without this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `,` operator to chain function calls, i.e.:

```
int main(){
    return printf("%s", isPalindrome(fgets(malloc(1000), 1000, stdin)) ? 
                 (free(p), "Yes!\n") : (free(p), "No!\n")) >= 0;
}
```

assuming you assign allocated buffor to `p` first.